# Problema com código javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho um problema com javascript, sim por falta de conhecimento da linguagem.

*É o seguinte, o código abaixo faz que uma música da lista de um busca reproduza ao clicar em "Play".*

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function PlayerRoduzir(id) {
        var id;
        change("https://api.xxxxxx.com/tracks/" + id +".mp3");
        var button1 = document.getElementById("play_" + id).style.display = "none";
        var button2 = document.getElementById("stop_" + id).style.display = "";
      }

    function PlayerParar(id){
        var id;
      var audio = document.getElementById("player");
      var source = document.getElementById("mp3_src");
      var button1 = document.getElementById("play_" + id).style.display = "";
      var button2 = document.getElementById("stop_" + id).style.display = "none";
      audio.pause();
    }
</script>
```

PHP/HTML:

```
<?php 
echo "<button type='button' id='play_".$id."' onClick='PlayerRoduzir(".$id.");' class='btn btn-info'><i class=\"fa fa-play-circle-o\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></button> ";
echo "<button type='button' style='display: none;' id='stop_".$id."' onClick='PlayerParar(".$id.");' class='btn btn-danger'><i class=\"fa fa-stop\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></button> ";
?>
```

**Quando clico em reproduzir o botão de reprodução fica vermelho com o sinal de STOP para parar, se eu clico volta o player.**

O problema é quando clico nos outros "play", os demais botões deviam ficar azul, mas não  fica vermelho, gostaria que ficasse azul e o vermelho somente na música que está tocando. Veja o exemplo de como está no momento na imagem abaixo:

[image: Exemplo]

> E ai, como concertar isso?

Comment: Quando clica num botão de `play` é necessário parar todos os outros por javascript, chamando a função de `PlayerParar` para cada um deles

Comment: Pode postar um exemplo por favor? Infelizmente não tenho experiência com JS.

Comment: Tem a class  do bootstrap, sendo **btn btn-info** para play e **btn btn-danger** para stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução mais simples para o seu problema é garantir que para todas as musicas param quando vai tocar uma nova. Para fazer isso pode percorrer todos os botões de `stop` por javascript e chamar as suas funções de `click`.

Assumindo que os seus botões de `stop` tem a `class` `btn btn-danger` como indicou nos comentários, necessita apenas de trocar a sua função de `PlayerRoduzir` para:

```
function PlayerRoduzir(id) {

    //obter todos os botões de stop
    const botoesStop = document.querySelectorAll(".btn.btn-danger");

    for (let botao of botoesStop){ //percorrer todos
        botao.click(); //chamar o click em cada um o que para todos
    }

    //aqui continua e toca aquele em que se fez play

    change("https://api.xxxxxx.com/tracks/" + id +".mp3");
    var button1 = document.getElementById("play_" + id).style.display = "none";
    var button2 = document.getElementById("stop_" + id).style.display = "";
}
```

---

Uma solução melhor e mais eficiente seria memorizar a ultima musica que fez `play` e parar apenas essa. Para isso é necessário uma nova variável para guardar o `id` da ultima tocada.

```
let idUltima = -1; //começa com -1 que indica que não tem nenhuma a tocar

function PlayerRoduzir(id) {
    if (idUltima != -1) { //se vai tocar mas ainda há outra a tocar
        PlayerParar(idUltima); //agora para a ultima que ainda estava a tocar
    }

    change("https://api.xxxxxx.com/tracks/" + id +".mp3");
    var button1 = document.getElementById("play_" + id).style.display = "none";
    var button2 = document.getElementById("stop_" + id).style.display = "";

    idUltima = id; //marca esta como a ultima musica a tocar
}

function PlayerParar(id){

    var audio = document.getElementById("player");
    var source = document.getElementById("mp3_src");
    var button1 = document.getElementById("play_" + id).style.display = "";
    var button2 = document.getElementById("stop_" + id).style.display = "none";
    audio.pause();

    idUltima = -1; //limpa a ultima musica a tocar
}
```

Notas:

- Remova os `var id;` que tem dentro das funções pois não fazem nada, já que o `id` refere o parâmetro da função e não essa variável.
- Pode ter que ajustar o seletor usado no primeiro exemplo, `.btn.btn-danger` para um mais especifico, mediante o *HTML* que tenha na sua página

Comment: A última debaixo foi bem mais fácil e eficiente! Funcionou certinho, muito obrigado pela a ajuda.

Comment: Oi vi aqui que os dois códigos não funciona no navegador  UC Browser e outros navegadores. A gente clica em play mais não vai. O que pode ser?

Comment: @Léo Pode ser que esse navegador que está a utilizar (que eu não conheço) não suporte a keyword `let` e/ou `const`. Experimente trocar por `var`.

Comment: @Léo O mesmo se aplica para o `for .. of` da primeira versão que pode não ser suportado em browsers antigos. Se for o caso troque por `for (var i = 0; i < botoesStop.length;++i){ botoesStop[i].click(); }`

Comment: troquei por var e deu certo. Obrigado  gênio!

Comment: Isac, se não for pedir muito, é difícil fazer que o botão volta a ficar azul do **play** quando a música terminar de tocar? Acho que só falta isso pra ficar perfeito.

Comment: @Léo Para fazer qualquer coisa quando acaba de tocar é necessario o evento de `ended` que seria aplicado na etiqueta de `<audio>` como `onended="funcao()"`. Nesse caso a função iria buscar o `<audio>` em que a musica acabou e adicionar a `class` de CSS que o mete azul. No entanto passa depois a ser necessário remover essa classe de azul assim que uma música começa a tocar.

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado!